# Show that $\sin^{-1}(\operatorname{cosec}x) = [2n + (-1)^n]\pi/2 + I(-1)^n \log(\cot x/2)$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

It is a question from hyperbolic and inverse hyperbolic functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the sine to both sides, use $\sin(x+k\pi)=(-1)^k\sin(x)=\sin((-1)^kx)$ to arrive at
$$
\frac1{\sin x}=\sin\left(\frac\pi2+i\log(\cot\frac x2)\right)=\cosh(\log(\cot\frac x2))=\frac1{2}\left(e^{\log(\cot\frac x2)}+e^{-\log(\cot\frac x2)}\right)
$$
so that in forward direction there are no contradictions. Now to go into the backwards direction you need to account for the branches of the inverse sine.